# Pandas map (reorder/rename) columns using JSON template

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so:

```
|customer_key|order_id|subtotal|address        |
------------------------------------------------
|12345       |O12356  |123.45  |123 Road Street|
|10986       |945764  |70.00   |634 Road Street|
|32576       |678366  |29.95   |369 Road Street|
|67896       |198266  |837.69  |785 Road Street|
```

And I would like to reorder/rename the columns based on the following JSON that contains the current column name and the desired column name:

```
{
"customer_key": "cust_id",
"order_id": "transaction_id",
"address": "shipping_address",
"subtotal": "subtotal"
}
```

to have the resulting Dataframe:

```
|cust_id|transaction_id|shipping_address|subtotal|
--------------------------------------------------
|12345  |O12356        |123 Road Street |123.45  |
|10986  |945764        |634 Road Street |70.00   |
|32576  |678366        |369 Road Street |29.95   |
|67896  |198266        |785 Road Street |837.69  |
```

is this something that's possible? if it makes it easier, the order of the columns isn't critical.

Comment: @anky_91 Does that also take care of reordering them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For renaming and ordering you would need to reindex after renaming

```
df.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=d.values())
```

or:

```
df.reindex(columns=d.keys()).rename(columns=d)
```

Comment: thank you!! just out of curiosity, do you know if this same approach works with pyspark dataframes?

Comment: @DBA108642 i have never worked with spark.  But i think the spark dfs are immutable so you might need a different approach. Not sure though just guessing

Comment: thanks, I posted the question and it does work with spark with a similar type of approach