# Pyspark map (reorder/rename) columns using JSON template

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I asked the following question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668727/pandas-map-reorder-rename-columns-using-json-template/59668840#59668840)

With the following text:

I have a data frame like so:

```
|customer_key|order_id|subtotal|address        |
------------------------------------------------
|12345       |O12356  |123.45  |123 Road Street|
|10986       |945764  |70.00   |634 Road Street|
|32576       |678366  |29.95   |369 Road Street|
|67896       |198266  |837.69  |785 Road Street|
```

And I would like to reorder/rename the columns based on the following JSON that contains the current column name and the desired column name:

```
{
"customer_key": "cust_id",
"order_id": "transaction_id",
"address": "shipping_address",
"subtotal": "subtotal"
}
```

To have the resulting Dataframe:

```
|cust_id|transaction_id|shipping_address|subtotal|
--------------------------------------------------
|12345  |O12356        |123 Road Street |123.45  |
|10986  |945764        |634 Road Street |70.00   |
|32576  |678366        |369 Road Street |29.95   |
|67896  |198266        |785 Road Street |837.69  |
```

Is this something that's possible? If it makes it easier, the order of the columns isn't critical.

The key difference is that I'm now looking for a way to do this in pyspark instead of pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use select with aliases:

```
select_expr = [col(c).alias(a) for c, a in mappings.items()]

df = df.select(*select_expr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the following:

```
new_mapping = {
"customer_key": "cust_id",
"order_id": "transaction_id",
"address": "shipping_address",
"subtotal": "subtotal"
}

for key, value in new_mapping.items():
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(key, value)

# Re-order df
new_columns = [col_name for col_name in new_mapping.values()]
df = df.select(*new_columns)
```

**Note**: Now the order depends on the dictionary. In Python 2 the dictinaries are unordered, so you have to use `OrderedDict`, in Python 3 the dicts have order and keep the insertion order.

Comment: And that would also take care of reordering them as well?

Comment: I edit the answer, take a look to the answer again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `toDF`:

```
dct = {
"customer_key": "cust_id",
"order_id": "transaction_id",
"address": "shipping_address",
"subtotal": "subtotal"
}

df.toDF(*[dct[col] for col in df.columns])
```